# How to change default directory alias in AWS SSO?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

AWS SSO doesn't allow changing directory alias. How can I do that? Is it possible to remove default directory or remove/disable whole SSO and configure it from the beginning or maybe from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your Directory Type**

You can change where you store users at any time. Use the following procedure to switch from a directory that AWS SSO provides (the default) to an AWS Managed Microsoft AD directory or vice versa.

**To change your directory type**

1. Open the AWS SSO console.
2. From the **Dashboard**, choose **Manage your directory**
3. On the **Directory page**, select **Change directory**.
4. On the **Change directory** page, select the directory you want to switch to, and then choose **Next**. If you are switching to a Microsoft AD directory, you must choose the available directory from the provided menu.

**Important**

Changing a directory removes all user assignments that were previously assigned. You must manually reapply these once you have successfully changed your directory.

5. Choose **Next: Review.**
6. Once you have read the disclaimer and are ready to proceed, type **CONFIRM**.
7. Choose **Finish**.

for more check [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/manage-your-directory-change.html)

Comment: My problem is that I have to remove created alias from default directory because I want to use this alias for my Microsoft AD Directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change default directory alias in AWS SSO. This is official answer.